# React list child checkbox is delayed on parent state changes

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Pretty sure I'm missing something obvious here!

I have a list component rendering a series of cards. Each card has a checkbox so that a user can select multiple items and then carry out an action on all items. I'm storing the list of items in the parent component, however this causes a delay to the checkbox visually changing.

Parent:

```js
const Results = ({results}) => {
  const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState([])
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Results</h2>
      {results.map((result) => (
        <Card
          key={result.id}
          selected={selected.includes(result.id)}
          onChange={() => {
            if (selected.includes(result.id) {
              setSelected(selected.filter((id) => id !== result.id))
            } else {
              setSelected([...selected, result.id])
            }
          }
        />
      )}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Child:

```js
const Card = ({selected, onChange}) => (
  <div>
    <input
      type="checkbox"
      selected={selected}
      onChange={onChange}
    />
  </div>
)
```

Is this because every time the checkbox changes, it's causing the parent to re-render itself and it's children? I can see that the actual updating of the list in the parents state happens quickly, but that the checkbox visual change is then delayed. What's the best way to ensure the checkbox changes responsively when clicked as well as updating the list of checked items in the parent?

**EDIT**

I've also tried with `useEffect`...

Parent:

```js
const Results = ({results}) => {
  const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState([])
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Results</h2>
      {results.map((result) => (
        <Card
          key={result.id}
          onChange={() => {
            if (selected.includes(result.id) {
              setSelected(selected.filter((id) => id !== result.id))
            } else {
              setSelected([...selected, result.id])
            }
          }
        />
      )}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Child:

```js
const Card = ({onChange}) => {
  const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState(false)

  React.useEffect(() => {
    onChange(fault.faultUuid)
  }, [selected])

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        selected={selected}
        onChange={() => setSelected(!selected)}
      />
    </div>
  )
}
```

**SOLUTION**

I found it, every component in the list was making a GraphQL request every time any checkbox was selected/deselected.

Comment: I've managed to solve this problem in redux by `Normalizing State`. You might be able to do something similar using the `useContext` hook. Here's a link to Normalizing State: https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/normalizing-state-shape

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to solve this by using memoization on your `Card` components.

Like this:

```
import React, { memo } from 'react'

const Card = memo(({selected, onChange}) => (
  <div>
    <input
      type="checkbox"
      selected={selected}
      onChange={onChange}
    />
  </div>
))
```

This means that your `Card` components will only re-render when their props change.

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't have any effect.

Comment: Actually, I'm going to mark this as the answer. Now that I've found the offending component, this solved my problem. Previously, it wasn't working because the problem is in a nested child component and I was using this on its parent. So, thanks!!